# How Do I Redirect HTTP(S) Requests From a Specific Domain to a Localhost Server?

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I currently have a program that requests data from a server (let's say google.com), and gets replies from that same server. This application works on many devices like Android, iOS and Windows. Deploying to this server is difficult, as the backend is huge, so what I would like to do is intercept that traffic and redirect it to a local server for development purposes on the entire network to see how it works across all of the devices it supports.

The application accesses the server and all of its subdomains (so `*.google.com`). What I would like to do it route all that traffic from my application to a completely different server, namely localhost, then deploy the backend after I am done editing it on localhost to the main server.

All of the traffic will resemble this diagram here

For all requests:

`*.google.com ---------> localhost:8080`

> Application expects it is requesting content from `*.google.com` but in fact it is requesting content from localhost at port `8080`

For responses:

`*.google.com <-------- localhost:8080`

> Application expects it is getting a response from `*.google.com` but gets a response from localhost at port `8080`. Request is completely the same format as if it were getting it from `*.google.com` so the application does not notice the difference besides different content.

I have setup my localhost server to automatically accept and recognize any requests the application asks for so the replies should not be an issue.

The only issue that arises is rerouting all that traffic for the entire network. I do not think it is impossible though, as I've seen network-wide utilities like pihole do similar things, where they use a filter to block specific domains that deal with ads. I do not mind having to change my DNS on multiple devices, as all I want is to have the ability to reroute any traffic as described above.

Is there any tool that is available that I will be able to use, or will I have to create my own? What resources are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this in different ways:

1. Performing destination-NAT on all IP addresses belonging to the target service. Thiss allows you to rewrite both the port and the destination IP of the packets.
2. Using a DNS-server with static entries. This will only let you modify the destination address, not the port.

Both approaches fit the requirement of achieving network-wide redirection. However, both of these approaches will break HTTPS. To properly intercept HTTPS you will need to:

1. Create HTTPS proxy
2. Register the certificate (or certification authority) of that proxy in each client application (e.g. within firefox)
3. Register the proxy to be used for certain traffic shapes in each client application.

As you can see you will likely have to either drop the requirement for HTTPS or for a network-wide solution.

Additionally, it is important to know that while the DNS-based approach (e.g. pihole) *should* work for the whole network you are susceptible to the "dumb client problem". Clients are not actually forced to use the DNS of their operating system. For example, some browsers have DoH activated by default; which circumvents the DNS configured on the OS.

Comment: After fully testing this solution thoroughly, I have validated that this (SOLUTION #2) works well. Although I must say that using a DNS server will not break HTTPS if the server you have is configured to handle and accept encrypted HTTPS traffic.